# Modifying auto-generated Fortran code with C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, fortran

I am working with a project where I am generating a significant amount of fortran code using an automated tool but then I need to do modifications to that code by hand prior to compiling.  These modifications have no specific pattern, other than that I know what sections of code need to be modified.  Furthermore, I need to be able to apply these modifications anytime I regenerate the base code, so it must be automated (for both speed and for consistency).  I'm quite aware that in an deal world the base product should be modified to simply generate the code properly.  However, that is not possible in this case.

What I'm wondering is what the cleanest way to do this would be in C#.  Currently the best plan I've been able to come up with is to create an xml file where each node has a set of text to replace with another set for a certain file.  I would then read all the xml files into my program and make the modifications detailed therein.  I believe this will work, and it is much more flexible than hard coding the modifications into my program, but I'm trying to determine if there is a more appropriate design pattern or extension, that could or should be used in this case.

Main concern is time required to code and extensibility (i.e. if I want to add more modifications later on, that I'm able to do so).  I have the full code for what it should look like, as well as what it currently looks like.

Is storing each find and replace snippet in a flat file a reasonable organizational structure?  Or is there a smarter way to approach this problem?

Comment: What about loading the generated code into the [CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6(v=vs.110).aspx) and creating code to modify it? The process is repeatable and may be less brittle than doing find/replace as a string.

Comment: I'd probably try and achieve the changes through inheritance or dependency injection, but really don't know the nature of your problem.  If BaseProduct, does method B incorrectly, then I will create MyProduct that implements method B correctly.  That said, that might not be possible here.

Comment: Interesting (CodeDOM), I haven't use this before.  The code I woud be modifying is fortran though... would that still work for somethin not object oriented?

Comment: I see, thought it was c# code.  I can't help with fortran

Comment: @Rob, it is fortran and only modifications to small snippets of code in each file.  The code base is highly coupled, so I hesitate to rewrite anything except for changes that I know are already OK and that don't break anything.  I do have the start and end result for each file, so I know what should be changed... just not the best way to modify the code.

Comment: I doubt CodeDOM would work with Fortran (unless there is a provider for Fortran). I would still be concerned that the generated code might change slightly and the find/replace would stop working because it is string-based rather than intention/structure based

Comment: Did you try to report your bug to the tool authors? If it's really a tool problem and not just your personal problem, they will maybe fix it for you in the next version.

Comment: Most of them are customizations of the code, and are unlikely to be built into the tool.  Also, while some things will be added in for new versions, the process of upgrading to a new version is a major undertaking requiring years, whereas I need to find a solution that can work on a shorter time interval.